# Find argument if two equation have common root .

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

> Two equations $a_1z^2 + b_1z +c_1 = 0$ and $a_2z^2 + b_2z +c_2 = 0$ where $a_i,b_i,c_i \in \mathbb C , i\in \{1,2\}$ have exactly one root common which is a positive real number . Also it is know that the equation $a_1z^2 + (b_1-1)z +c_1 = 0$ and $a_2z^2 + (b_2-1)z +c_2 = 0$ also have exactly one common root ,which is another positive real ,then answer the following :
>   $$1.\arg\left(\frac{b_1-b_2}{a_1-a_2}\right)$$
>   $$2.\arg\left(\frac{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}{a_1-a_2}+\frac{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}{c_2-c_1}\right)$$

My Work 
$$\frac{{{\alpha}_1}^2}{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}=\frac{-{\alpha}_1}{a_1c_2-a_2c_1}=\frac{1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}
$$
$$\implies \frac{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}{a_1c_2-a_2c_1}=\frac{a_1c_2-a_2c_1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}$$
Similarly 
$$\implies \frac{(b_1-1)c_2-(b_2-1)c_1}{a_1c_2-a_2c_1}=\frac{a_1c_2-a_2c_1}{a_1(b_2-1)-a_2(b_1-1)}$$
Dividing both the expressions 
$$\frac{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}{(b_1-1)c_2-(b_2-1)c_1}=\frac{a_1(b_2-1)-a_2(b_1-1)}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}$$
$$\frac{c_2-c_1}{(b_1-1)c_2-(b_2-1)c_1}=\frac{a_2-a_1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}$$
$$\frac{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}{a_2-a_1}=\frac{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}{c_2-c_1}-1$$
$$\frac{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}{a_1-a_2}+\frac{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}{c_2-c_1}=1$$
But for first part I am not able to solve
 .

Comment: Does **#1** correspond to first equation pair while **#2** the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $x_1 \ne x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^+$ be the common real positive roots of the two pairs of equations. Then:

$$
(a_1-a_2)x_1^2 + (b_1-b_2)x_1 + (c_1-c_2) = 0
$$
$$
(a_1-a_2)x_2^2 + (b_1-b_2)x_2 + (c_1-c_2) = 0
$$

Since $x_1 \ne x_2$ it follows that $x_1,x_2$ are the two distinct roots of:

$$
(a_1-a_2)z^2 + (b_1-b_2)z + (c_1-c_2) = 0
$$

which implies $a_1 \ne a_2$ and:

$$
x_1+x_2 = -\,\frac{b_1-b_2}{a_1-a_2} \;\;\in\;\;\mathbb{R}^+
$$

so $\arg\big(\frac{b_1-b_2}{a_1-a_2} \big) = \cdots$